# Store and retrieve array list in Bundle in Android

Tags: android, android-bundle

How do I store and retrieve an array list of values in a [`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) in Android? Any examples?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lets take if you array list has strings in it.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("test1");
al.add("test2");
al.add("test3");
```

Now you can put it into bundle as follows:

```
Bundle value= new Bundle();
value.putStringArrayList("temp1", al);
```

If you have your own object type instead of "String" in ArrayList then you need to serialize that ArrayList object.

Comment: I'm wondering what is the reasoning behind these API methods using ArrayLists rather than Lists?

Comment: @jramoyo You can use list, but mohan asked for ArrayList so.

Answer (score 3):

Serialize your arraylist using the [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) class. You can add Parcelables to the Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to store an arraylist in bundle, if this arraylist can not be explain as an array of any primary type (int, char, etc...), is to serialize the data and to store it in the bundle as serializable.