# Unable to pass String and List<String> at the same time using Bundle in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send `String` and `List<String>` from one activity to another activity using the following code in first activity:

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Activity2);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("IDs", (ArrayList<String>) ids);
intent1.putExtra("message","IDs");
intent1.putExtras(b);
```

And I am accessing this content in second activity as follows:

```
 Bundle b= intent.getExtras();
 String str=b.getString("message");
 ArrayList<String> list=b.getStringArrayList("IDs");
```

The problem is: I am getting `str` as `null` even though `list` is getting correct values. Am I missing something in using the `Bundle`?

Comment: Please explain your problem better.  You have provided contradictory information.  In your title, you state "Unable to pass String and List<String>", yet in your description, you state "list" is getting correct values".  Which is it?  Does the List<String> parameter make it to the 2nd activity or not?

Comment: @Kiran see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303800/how-to-store-and-retrieve-array-list-value-in-bundle-in-android

Comment: I think this has been answered here ->
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768969/passing-a-bundle-on-startactivity

Comment: @EJK Hi, I am sorry for that. I am sending both at the same time but only List is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Activity2);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("IDs", (ArrayList<String>) ids);
b.putExtra("message","IDs");
intent1.putExtras(b);
```

Instead of using

```
Intent intent1=new Intent(Activity2);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayList("IDs", (ArrayList<String>) ids);
intent1.putExtra("message","IDs");
intent1.putExtras(b);
```

---

The reason is `putExtras` replaces all the previous value which is set to `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is, You are passing   'message' as intent and trying to get it from bundle

```
intent1.putExtra("message","IDs");
```

Instead use

```
b.putString("message","IDs");
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the extar parameter like this

```
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);

        searchUserIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("IDs", ids);

        startActivity(searchUserIntent);
```

And to get the intent parameters use

```
            Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    ids2 = intent2.getStringArrayListExtra("IDs");
```